# sync all Chrome extensions but keep disable/enabled options local?

Tags: google-chrome, sync, google-chrome-extensions

Can I make Chrome sync all my extensions and apps across all my machines but keep disable/enabled options local?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a feature that I've tried (There may be dragons ahead) but it sounds like it should do what you are looking for.

1. Open Chrome Settings.
2. Right at the top, under Sign-in, there is an Advanced Sync Options button.
3. Click that.
4. Deselect the option to sync settings.

It's the best bet that I've come across.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can do it.
I tried this with my desktop and laptop and disable/enable options can be kept local to the system but extension can't

Answer (score 0):

in chrome settings (for the machine(s))which you wish to not have sync in the cloud  simply   select disconnect account ( stays locally but all syncing on OTHER devices keeps trucking along)